# Two part operator in Swift

Tags: swift, linear-algebra, physics

In the [swift book](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html), it says that you can declare an operator as either `infix`, `postfix` or `prefix`.
I wanted to implement [Dirac notation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/concepts/dirac-notation?view=qsharp-preview) in Swift, e.g. `⟨x|Ĥ|x⟩`.

I was originally thinking of just using `|x⟩` as the variable name for the tensor and implementing `ᵀ` as a transpose operator, but that leads to an ugly |x⟩ᵀ Ĥ |x⟩, which defeats the point of making it human-readable.

For simplicity, it would be the same as implementing `⌊x⌋` as the floor function.

Is there a way of having a two-part operator in swift?

Comment: This is as close as I could get: https://gist.github.com/amomchilov/fbda58948f48d9209d216e13f893245c

But honestly, I wouldn't recommedn this.

Comment: I agree that this is a bad path. You might come up with something clever (like https://gist.github.com/rnapier/e64a4454b0efde1ca897b036eff158bf), but it's going to have a lot of sharp edges (see the same gist…) where it doesn't work the way you expect. Think about how to adapt tensors to Swift syntax, not how to force a specific syntax onto Swift. Swift is not that flexible. If you feel this is an important feature, I would bring it to swift-evolution to expand the language to support it.

Comment: (but I also secretly hope someone posts an awesome answer to this… :D)